# How can I set in bold the column name displayed in a group-by view?

Tags: grouping

I'd like to highlight the name of the grouped-by columns in a view. I do not have SharePoint Designer (prohibited in our department by the IT Security...)

Can anybody help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a script editor web part on the page (view) where you want it to be bold and then use CSS to style it any way you want.

```
<style type="text/css">
.ms-gb {
font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
```